# Changing a string in a List using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of of road names and would like it iterate through them and change where it finds "Adams Road 1a", "Adams Road 2a" ... To just "Adams Road".

The code below will just change one of them items in the list.

I would like to change all of them.

```
communityHouses[communityHouses.FindIndex(
ind => ind.Road.Contains("Adams Road"))].Road= "Adams Road";
```

Comment: So, basically, you have already implemented an algorithm to do this, you only need to translate it to code. You write: I would like it iterate through them (`foreach`) and change (assign) where it finds (`if`).

Comment: I've created a foreach to solve the issue. I was just see how to do it with a lambda expression.

Comment: If you do this just for curiosity, then it's good. But in general it isn't a good idea to use lambda expressions for iterating over objects and changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `List<T>.ForEach` method.

```
communityHouses.ForEach(ch =>
{
    if (ch.Road.Contains("Adams Road")) ch.Road = "Adams Road";
});
```

Update:

Thanks @Flater's suggestion.

```
communityHouses.Where(ch => ch.Road.Contains("Adams Road"))
               .ToList().
               .ForEach(ch => ch.Road = "Adams Road");
```

I've also done some performance test and the first one always performs better than the second one.

Here's my test:

```
public class House
{
    public string Road { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<House> list1 = new List<House>();
        List<House> list2 = new List<House>();
        var sample = 50000;
        for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                list1.Add(new House() {Road = "Adam Road 1"});
                list2.Add(new House() {Road = "Adam Road 1"});
            }
            else
            {
                list1.Add(new House(){Road = "Random"});
                list2.Add(new House(){Road = "Random"});   
            }
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine("Test " + sample + " samples:");
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        list1.ForEach(l =>
        {
            if (l.Road.Contains("Adam Road")) l.Road = "Adams Road";
        });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("1 - ForEach: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        list2.Where(l=> l.Road.Contains("Adam Road")).ToList().ForEach(l =>
        
            l.Road = "Adams Road"
        );
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Where.ToList.ForEach: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    }
}
```

Test Result:

> Test 50000 samples:
>
> 1 - ForEach: 2 ms
>
> 2 - Where.ToList.ForEach: 3 ms
>
> Test 500000 samples:
>
> 1 - ForEach: 18 ms
>
> 2 - Where.ToList.ForEach: 21 ms
>
> Test 5000000 samples:
>
> 1 - ForEach: 179 ms
>
> 2 - Where.ToList.ForEach: 221 ms

Update:

I did another test where I changed the `i % 3` to `i % 10000` and now the second one performed better.

I would say it's really doesn't matter which one to use. Just choose the one you feel more clean and understandable. I will go for the second.

Comment: I'd consider using `communityHouses.Where(ch => ch.Road.Contains("Adams Road")).ForEach()` instead of doing the check in the iteration. It doesn't quite matter now but for heavier operations it might start making a performance difference (it also reduces nesting).

Comment: I've made some test to use `ForEach` against `.Where.ToList.ForEach`. seems the second always performs better than `ForEach`. Thanks for your advice, I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The first one performs better than the second one.